# What's the most expensive parking spot in the world?

Tags: automobiles, where-on-earth

Recently I've traveled to Salt Lake City and noticed that there was a "Premium Reserved Parking" section for [$10/hour](https://slcairport.com/parking-and-transportation/parking/parking-garage/), which seemed like the highest hourly rate I've seen so far. Are there parking spots that are even more expensive?

Here's the full list of conditions:

- This must be a regular parking rate, not a one-time special price. So a parking lot that charged solar eclipse visitors $100/hour won't count.
- If there's a discount for staying longer, you don't have to apply it. In the case of Salt Lake City airport above, there's a cheaper option for $55/day, but it would still count as $10/hour as that's the base rate someone would have to pay.
- If the parking rate is for a fixed number of hours (common for "event" rates), you must divide the amount paid by the maximum number of hours allowed for that amount of money. If the maximum number of hours is not clearly defined, you must divide that rate by 4, as a rough proxy to how long events usually last.
- This parking lot must be accessible to the general public
- It has to be self-service parking, rather than valet parking
- The largest parking fee prorated per hour wins. So if there's a $1000/month rate somewhere, it would count as $1.38/hour after diving by the maximum number of hours allowed at that location.
- This has to be an actual business that routinely makes money from selling their parking services. So a random house owner posting a $1m/hour rate next to his garage won't count.

Comment: Is this a good question? are we going to get more than  https://business.parkopedia.com/2019-global-parking-index ?

Comment: @chx I think it fits within the mood of the [where-on-earth] tag. Parkopedia's report provides average values, so surely there's outliers well outside the $40/2 hours they quote for NYC?

Comment: I don't think this is a good question. It's an unimportant piece of trivia that might be valid for one point in time but could change at any time in the future. It can even change with fluctuations in global currency values.

Comment: $10/hr is not a high cost for parking, at all. I paid $20 for a single hour at the King Edward Hotel in Toronto over 20 years ago.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. The cost of parking affects residents every bit as much, or more than, it affects travelers.

Comment: It took a fair bit of money to put Elon Musk's old Roadster where it is now, and it's not like he's currently using it.  Does that count as parking it?

Comment: The cost of parking the Tesla Roadster in space.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert No. "This must be a regular parking rate, not a one-time special price."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That's true for many open questions that receive many upvotes e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2539/1810

Comment: @GregHewgill "unimportant"  is subjective. Global currency values fluctuate a bit, but the $1.3 million parking spot https://www.caranddriver.com/news/a36641310/parking-space-hong-kong-price-1-3-million it still going to be high in the list (I know this question is about renting).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that counts, but the [Gatwick Airport Drop-off charge](https://www.gatwickairport.com/to-and-from/picking-up-dropping-off/) is £5 for 10 minutes (so £30/hour), then £1/minute for the next 20 minutes (£60/hour).

Very short-term drop-off or pick-up areas in airports and the like are probably good candidates.

Comment: Are you allowed to leave your car at the drop off spot?

Comment: @JonathanReez there’s a maximum of 30 minutes (no idea what happens after that), but I suppose you can leave your car for a few minutes to help the people you are dropping off get into the terminal with their luggage. You could probably pop into one of the shops if you wanted, though that would result in a pretty expensive snack or drink :-)